# Width height of the svg is not changing

Tags: javascript, html, svg

When i try to change the height and width of the of svg tag it changed but the map inside grts cut .

this is the sample of the svg file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg width="500pt" height="500pt" viewBox="0 0 500 500" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g transform="translate(528,270)" > 
        <g id="states" fill="green" width="500pt" height="500pt" >
            <a id="s01">
                <path d="M158.95067408594068,46.88327098850149L185.03303599629845,44.0148159910488L189.74121811302572,59.50889743727097L196.59587401503094,82.27898337817625L199.0518321008348,87.17077847298319L201.13017099189912,89.85649424407167L200.707578706067,91.7588142001174L202.6261541288344,92.6205139503571L200.33524838576966,95.29216920133321L200.7363444144292,97.59217497211156L199.80999341478454,100.8918397716738L202.09021078470892,106.20782432993735L201.64399529140977,111.17790897235179L204.03767592952832,115.96122130827978L196.3574723373462,117.09985438789514L163.47293491613115,121.08122011183377L163.22294648718562,123.55296427740802L167.13791879442175,126.6835133291724L166.871741037497,129.76735843938286L168.2485001228969,131.1400084527912L166.21795234496457,134.1137855808483L164.12121282499038,134.9547500732084L159.81791064191435,132.36796011584426L158.90469329765804,127.88713803963412L157.64560372254968,127.51168600895127L156.5390262005875,131.08669596034315L156.36678872306632,134.46030822963786L152.20800610122825,133.97284127048096L148.16895577705603,105.98121856614907L148.12136132417422,70.56398790998259L148.15893441899317,50.102043132249676L146.40831263672231,48.33943105796875Z" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-dasharray="1, 0" stroke-width="1.5"></path>
                <text x="162.66165594858754" y="86.92631614090374" style="">AL</text>
                <title></title>
            </a>
            <a id="s02">
```

Comment: Do you want to shrink it? Anyway, changing the size of the container has no effect on the child-nodes. You have to apply a scale transformation.

Comment: ZimTis is incorrect.  The file has a viewBox attribute, so changing the width and height attributes should alter the size of the image on the page.  It is not clear what exactly the problem is that you are experiencing.  Can you post images, or a fiddle perhaps?

Comment: Sry, didn't see that, thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 1):

After playing with your sample, I think I have a idea of what might be happening.

What did you do to your file to try and resize it?  Did you alter the width and height, or did you change the `viewBox` value?  Or both?

In the snippet you posted, the outline of Alabama is off the right hand edge of the picture.  That is because of the transform in the first group:

```
transform="translate(528,270)"
```

which is moving the Alabama origin to 528,270, which is off the edge of the diagram as defined by the viewBox (500x500).

So changing the width and height, won't bring Alabama back onto the page.  You have to alter the viewBox so that it encompasses the part of the page where Alabama is.  So, for example, if you change it to:

```
viewBox="0 0 1000 500"
```

Alabama will now be visible, and you can then change the size of the map to whatever you want.

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/6J5AJ/)

In summary, `viewBox` (x y width height) describes the bounds of the content of the page.  `width` and `height` tell the renderer how big to scale the area described by the viewBox.
So in this case, all the content in that 1000x500 viewbox will be scaled so that it fits in the box defined by the width and height (500x500).  So, in actual fact, the map will be scaled down for these values (1000x500 down to 500x250).

Comment: @bigBadboom   ACtualy when i change the width height and viewbox parameter i want that the svg should get small and fitt in to the view box . Thanks

Comment: when i change the width height of the view box graphics inside the view box doesnt change the size and but it gets cut

Comment: If there is content that is outside the edge of the image then you need to change the `viewBox` (only) so that it is larger than all your content.  Adjust the viewBox x,y,width and height so that it is a close fit to your content.  Once all the content is visible, you can then play with `<svg>` width and height so that the image is the size you want on the page.